# How to host .NET 6 Web API as Windows Service?

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-services, asp.net-core-webapi, hosting, .net-6.0

I have .NET 6 Web API and want to host as a windows service on my own virtual server. I read many questions and answers and applied them, but I still get an error when starting the application **(error 1053: the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion)** Also I couldn't find a detailed error description when I looked in the event log.

I'm using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices package and Program.cs is below

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(new WebApplicationOptions
{
    Args = args,
    ContentRootPath = WindowsServiceHelpers.IsWindowsService() ? AppContext.BaseDirectory : default
});
builder.Host.UseWindowsService();
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MongoDB");
...
```

I'm developing on MAC so publishing my codes with the following command

```
dotnet publish --runtime win7-x64 --self-contained  --configuration Release
```

I'm creating my windows service like this

```
sc create "MySvc" binPath= "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test\MySvc.exe"
```

Where am I doing wrong or how can I find the error?

Comment: Hi @Kenan Nur, could you pls make sure open log event and check the log what's the error message?